# Javascript Remove [] from array?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array

```
 [Array(1), Array(1), Array(0)]
```

Here is the formatted version

```
[{…}]
[{…}]
[]
```

How can I remove [] ?

Comment: Can you give more details on it., Is that mean, you want to remove empty arrays?

Comment: What about `mainArray.pop()` ? :-D

Answer (score 13):

So you have an array of arrays & you want to remove the empty array?

You can filter out the values you don't want by using `.filter`

E.g

```
const arr = [ [], ['1', '2'], ['3', '4'] ].filter(v => v.length > 0);
```

Comment: update your sample as const arr = [ [], ['1', '2'], ['3', '4'] ].filter(v => v.length > 0);

Answer (score 6):

Try to use filter, this will iterate through the your array and will return array item which are having length greater than 0

```
result = obj.filter(x=> x.length > 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check the length of your internal array to determine whether you should keep the value when you filter the array.

```js
const arr = [Array(1), Array(1), Array(0)]

console.log(
  arr.filter(x => x && x.length)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```